# Properly Handle NA in Single Column when Running Several Regressions

Tags: r, na, lm

I am attempting to use `lm` to calculate the average when a dummy variable is true. I have a data frame with three cols (Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, and Dummy). When one of the cols contains an `NA`, the entire row is excluded (even though I am running two separate regressions) leading to the incorrect means. How do I properly run several regressions (without a for loop) that does not exclude the entire rows when only one col contains the `NA`?

```
# setup mydata
mydata <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(NA, NA, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Dummy = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

mydata

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Dummy
# 1          5.1          NA     1
# 2          4.9          NA     1
# 3          4.7         3.2     1
# 4          4.6         3.1     0
# 5          5.0         3.6     0
# 6          5.4         3.9     0

# reg Sepal.Length ~ Dummy, Sepal.Width ~ Dummy    
fit <- lm(data.matrix(mydata) ~ data.matrix(mydata["Dummy"]))

intercepts <- fit$coefficients[1,]
betas <- fit$coefficients[2,]

# calculate average when Dummy==1
intercepts + betas

# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width        Dummy 
#         4.7          3.2          1.0 

# calculate average when Dummy==1 (does not match)
apply(data.matrix(mydata %>% filter(Dummy==1)), 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width        Dummy 
#         4.9          3.2          1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work if you use `map` from `purrr` following [this](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/multiple-lm-purrr2/) example.

```
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

mydata %>% map(~lm(.x ~ Dummy, data=mydata)) %>% map("coefficients") %>% map(sum)

# $Sepal.Length
# [1] 4.9

# $Sepal.Width
# [1] 3.2

# $Dummy
# [1] 1
```